# Images not uploading to the Firebase Storage while implementing FireChat in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage

I am following the Google Docs for implementing the FireChat in my iOS application. But while trying to upload the images it shows the following error in console.

> Permission denied. Could not access bucket friendlychat-60f4e.appspot.com. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources.

This is my Firebase console screenshot:

[image]

Please help what i have to do now.

Comment: you have to change the rules for read and write.

Answer (score 3):

Default Storage Security Rules requires Firebase Authentication in order to perform any read or write operations. You should change this rule if you want to read/write without firebase authentication.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hey Jessica .... Here is the solution which is worked for me**
You should go in your firebase database... after that click on rules tab and after write true in read and write... here is the image which help you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is cause because we are not authenticate here the solution is go to Firebase Project -> Click on Storage -> Click on Rule 
This image that rules is default 
[image]

so we need to do this remove if request.auth != null that condition like in this image

[image]

and then it's working !! Thank You if it not working then please tell me so i can update my answer Happy Coding make sure to publish your change